# Change something in database based on

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am currently building a Mongo, Node, Express web app where deals are rendered on the screen in a list if they are "active" . However, I would like to programtically change the "active" status of a deal to (see below for dealSchema) at the "dealEndingDate".  Think of it like a deal expiring. Is there some sort of listener I can add to constantly troll the database and update the documents... I welcome all suggestions. Thank you!

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a63c974aa17eb49c5260815"
    },
    "dealHeadline": "Test",
    "active": true,
    "dealBeginningTime": {
        "$date": "2018-01-20T06:00:00.000Z"},
    "dealEndingTime": {
        "$date": "2018-01-22T23:45:00.000Z"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A cronjob can be a solution for you .

Comment: Do you have any recommended packages?

Comment: One of the best out there is Node-schedule

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of doing this is to use `expires`, i.e. `dealEndingTime: { type: Date, expires: '60s' }`. Please note that this will remove the entire `document` 60 seconds after the set date. If you still want to keep the `document`, you can set up a separate `Deal` collection, where all your deals are stored. Then you can reference the deals for each `document` by using `ObjectId`: `deals: [{_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'deal' }` Then simply checking the length of the `array` will reveal if there are any active deals for that `document`.

I hope this is useful to you!